# Why in $e^+ e^-\rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$ there is only two $S_F$ propagator instead of four from path integral?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, fermions, scattering-cross-section

This was a homework to calculate the $e^+ e^-\rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$ following Peskin & Schroeder chapter 5.1. However, I got confused with the path integral aspect of the calculation.(Which was not the homework)

The canonical quantization to calculate the $e^+ e^-\rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$ given in Peskin on page 131 was quite standard with the Feynman rule.
$$iM =\bar v^{s'}(p')(-ie\gamma^\mu) u^s(p) (\frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}) \bar u^r(k)(-ie\gamma^\nu)v^{r'}(k')$$

However, if one look at the path integral
$$Z_0 \exp[-\int dx^4 \int dy^4 \bar\eta(x) D_F(x-y) \eta (y) -\frac{1}{2} \int dx^4\int dy^4 A^\mu(x) D_{F_{\mu\nu}} (x-y) A^\nu(y)] $$

Then, in sketch
$$\langle 0|\bar \psi(x_1) \psi (x_2)  \bar \psi(x_3) \psi (x_4)    |0\rangle  $$
involving the insertion of $(-e\int dx^4 \bar\psi(x) \gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi(x))^2$
should produce the trace of four $$Tr[S_F S_F S_F S_F]$$ which got connected with the four external legs $$\bar \psi(x_1) \psi (x_2)  \bar \psi(x_3) \psi (x_4)$$ and with one photon propagator.

However, though the counting for the photon propagator was correct, there was the trace for only two of the $Tr[S_FS_F]$ in the momentum space for $iM$.

Where was the additional two fermionic propagator $S_F$ in the trace?

Comment: The $S_F(x-y)$ was in involved and in fact must be involved. My professor helped me clear it out. The issue was with the LSZ reduction formula, where the fermionic case was different than the bosonic case, and it exactly canceled out the four fermionic propagators. It's that almost no one(students) compute the "amputed function" directly from the path integral, so no one had mentioned that the LSZ reduction formula took a different from in the fermionic case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula#Reduction_formula_for_fermions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your answer there are two confusions going on here.

The first is that in the calculation of the tree matrix element for the $e^+e^-\to \mu^+\mu^-$ reaction there are actually no fermionic propagators involved. You can see it already in the expression for $iM$ that you provided. The only propagator involved (inverse powers of momenta, to make it simple) comes from the intermediate photon propagator. I think you might be getting confused with the fact that, when we sum over initial spins and average over final spins, we also get two traces. Those are, however, not propagators, but rather completeness relations for the fermionic spinors. In fact, they go as positive powers of the momentum, not inverse ones.

So, no fermionic propagator should appear in $iM$ for this process.

The fact that, instead, if you compute the four-point function from the generating functional you get four fermion propagator is completely natural. They correspond to the external legs of the diagram, which diverge when they are on-shell.
The confusion here is that $n$-point functions and scattering matrix elements are not the same thing. Roughly speaking, they are related to each other by the "truncation" of external legs, which schematically means (for example for the four point function):

$$
iM_4(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4) \sim S_F^{-1}(k_1)S_F^{-1}(k_2)S_F^{-1}(k_3)S_F^{-1}(k_4) \langle 0 | \bar\psi(k_1) \bar \psi(k_2) \bar\psi(k_3)\bar\psi(k_4)|0\rangle\,,
$$

where the role of the inverse propagator is precisely to "truncate" the external legs, and take care of the on-shell divergences.

The more rigorous procedure to connect $n$-point functions with $n$-point scattering matrix elements is called LSZ reduction.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The $S_F(x-y)$ was in involved and in fact must be involved. My professor helped me clear it out. The issue was with the LSZ reduction formula, where the fermionic case was different than the bosonic case, and it exactly canceled out the four fermionic propagators. It's that almost no one(students) compute the "amputed function" directly from the path integral, so no one had mentioned that the LSZ reduction formula took a different from in the fermionic case.

Comment: Where does the fermionic propagator enter exactly in the matrix element?

Comment: They were appear when connected to the in field and out field, and was canceled out in the LSZ formula.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Let me stress again though that there is no propagator in the matrix element. There are only propagators  in the correlator.